# URL/Image Downloader

Tags: download, download-manager

Can anyone suggest a good software that lets you download file urls or image urls and put it on an organize structure you specify.

let say i have a bunch of images to download that is structure like this.

> http://website.com/foods/vegetable/lettuce.jpg
>
> http://website.com/foods/vegetable/eggplant.jpg
>
> http://website.com/foods/vegetable/celery.jpg
>
> http://website.com/animals/pets/cat.jpg
>
> http://website.com/animals/pets/dog.jpg
>
> http://website.com/animals/pets/hamster.jpg

I want to place it on my folder like this:

> /Users/username/Documents/Downloads/vegetable/lettuce.jpg
>
> /Users/username/Documents/Downloads/vegetable/eggplant.jpg
>
> /Users/username/Documents/Downloads/vegetable/celery.jpg
>
> /Users/username/Documents/Downloads/pets/cat.jpg
>
> /Users/username/Documents/Downloads/pets/dog.jpg
>
> /Users/username/Documents/Downloads/pets/hamster.jpg

Notice that when i downloaded the images, i am only interested in placing them in the secondary directory ("**vegetable**" and "**pets**") and didn't include the first directory anymore...

Is there any software that let me do this?

I have a MACOSX and Also have a Windows 7, So any would do for me.

Thank You.